# System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException on empty table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, insert

I get this error:

```
System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.
```

When I run this code, which walks a directory and puts associated records in a database.

```
   public string RefreshClientTable(string username, string companyName) {
        string company_path = @"M:/" + companyName + "/Clients/";
        string info = "";
        ExplorerBAL b = new ExplorerBAL();
        List<Explorer.DirModel> c = b.Explorer(company_path).dirModelList;
        DataContext dbContext = new BaseDataContext();
        var db_company_clients = dbContext.Clients.Where(d => d.co_name == companyName).ToList();
        foreach (var client_name in c) {
            //Determine if client exists
            info = info + "Found: " + client_name.DirName + "\n";
            int client_in_db = dbContext.Clients.Count(f => f.co_name == companyName && f.cl_name == client_name.DirName);
            if (client_in_db == 1) {
                //Update ancillary fields (later)
            }
            else {
                info = info + "Updating: " + client_name.DirName + "\n";
                //Insert the record if non-existant
                Project insert_sql = new Project() {
                    co_name = companyName,
                    cl_name = client_name.DirName
                    //Update ancillary fields (later)
                };
                dbContext.Projects.InsertOnSubmit(insert_sql);
            }
        }

        try {
            dbContext.SubmitChanges();
            return "SUCCESS:\n" + info;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return "ERROR:\n" + info + e.ToString() + "\n";
        }
    }
```

Note that the tables are empty and the primary keys are two varchar fields. Based on research I suspect its some kind of an issue with the multiple calls to dbContext. I suspect it would work if I wasn't first checking for the existing of the item, but I really need to do that.

Does any one know anything about this issue? There are similar questions, but no suitable answers... yet inserting into a table is a very common operation so something must be very specifically wrong.

Comment: Since you say that `primary keys are two varchar fields` are you sure that you are not populating one of the keys before your insert?

Comment: Better to show tables structure here. The exception `DuplicateKeyException` often thrown when attempting to insert without instantiating table class/object, inserting a row with existing PK value or forgot to declare a PK column as auto-increment when required.

Comment: Its not an auto increment issue because its not a number, the table is empty and no rows are added when code is run so it can't be existing PK (unless maybe keys previously inserted into this funky visual studio dmcl model thingy are still in there, but not the database). I'm not sure about instantiation, so I tried rebuilding the .dmcl file (deleting all tables, re-importing and renaming as required). No effect. The error occurs when I submit changes. More of the error: "System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.TrackUntrackedObjects(MetaType type, Object item, Dictionary`2 visited)"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I hate to solve an 8 hour long problem with a typo solution. But here it is:

```
dbContext.Projects.InsertOnSubmit(insert_sql);
```

should have been:

```
dbContext.Clients.InsertOnSubmit(insert_sql);
```

Copy/paste error